# Run job that take result of stored procedure and insert it in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In SQLServer I have a stored procedure `my_sp` that returns a table .

I want to create a job that runs everyday and take the result of `my_sp`
and insert the values in another table `my_table` that matches the columns of `my_sp`

I've created a job and I wrote below script

```
insert [MyDB].[dbo].[my_table]
(
coulmnName1 ,
coulmnName2,
... 
)
exec my_sp
```

But the job failed and it says `my_table is invalid object name`

The table is already exists.

Comment: The error suggest is does not, or that that you don't have permission to access said table (and you've omitted that part of the error). The SQL suggests that the procedure and table are in different databases; did you perhaps create the table in the wrong database?

Comment: You need to create the table before you can insert into it.

Comment: @Larnu I do have access , I even tried to insert some data manually using insert into and data is inserted

Comment: @GordonLinoff Table is created

Comment: Then the above will work, @Rahul . There's something you're not telling us here.